# Marketing preferences in a checkout process

Tags: usability, gui-design, checkout, preferences

I can see there's different approaches to showing the marketing preferences when buying a product. In your opinion, if the marketing preferences has a long text and a long list of opt-ins, do you think it's advisable to have these in an accordion/expandable section, like the one below [image]

Or do you think they should all be shown like the following example[image]

Cheers!

Comment: Following GDPR standards the fist version, with elements in an expandable section wouldn't be compliant. 

"The GDPR lists specific requirements for lawful consent requests, but must also be given with a clear affirmative action. In other words, individuals need a mechanism that requires a deliberate action to opt in, as opposed to pre-ticked boxes. ... Opt-out options “are essentially the same as pre-ticked boxes, which are banned”."

https://www.itgovernance.eu/blog/en/gdpr-when-do-you-need-to-seek-consent

Comment: Could you explain why the GDPR has to be in the Checkout process, please? IMO this is shown to the user the moment they open the website for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

**You should not bother users with marketing decisions during checkout, it’s damaging the conversion rate**.

The users’ objective is to complete the checkout.
The business’s main objective is that they complete the checkout.
Keep diversions out of the way.

That’s basically the learning from the [$300 Million Button](https://articles.uie.com/three_hund_million_button/). Forcing users to create an account to checkout leads to abandoned carts.

> “I’m Not Here To Be In a Relationship”

I see a parallel here with marketing opt-ins.

Imagine a customer standing in store at the counter, money in their hands to pay for their shopping. Would you really bother asking these questions before securing the transaction?

While I’m not a fan of making people buy stuff ever more easily, leading to mindless consumption, this should not be the way to make them rethink. (;

Also, if this block of marketing agreements stands in the way of achieving the goal, it will be perceived negatively, so users will be less likely to opt-in to any of these at that moment.

Hence, it is very likely that they simply get ignored if hidden in an expandable. If these are options the user needs to opt-out from, that solution would be unacceptable, a dark pattern.

Offering these choices *after checkout* will lead to higher user satisfaction and conversion rates, while also improving the marketing messages retention.

In that case, it would be natural for them to be expanded on the confirmation page.

See also
[Luke Wroblewski’s Mobile Design Details: Don’t Divert the Train](https://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?1798)

Answer (score 0):

**What are the objectives of the business? Do they want to drive people to opt-in to top these marketing preferences?**

Until you know this would drive the solution you go with.

So with that in mind, without any testing and based on assumption, there are 2 things you could look at that will be the likely outcomes based on the answer to the above question:

- (Yes) If the business wants to drive people to select/opt into these marketing preferences then keep them exposed and on one page (second option).
- (No) If this isn't a priority for the business i.e. this isn't the main focus. Then go with the first expandable/accordion option.

But you need to ask them if people opting into marketing options is a goal. It's likely that the answer to this will be yes having worked with clients in general.

One point would be to test this. People may react to this differently, they could see all those options and just ignore them, who knows, but testing will iron out these things.

You could also look at where these are positioned in the flow, they don't all need to be before the buy button, they could appear on a success/thanks for your order page. Again this would depend on the business objective.

Answer (score 0):

Show it open as per the second option.

Basically you are asking for consent.  When requesting consent, one should be clear in the messaging.  Hiding options (even if just to save some screen space) can and probably will be interpreted as deceptive.